# Search in MongoDB with multiple field using $or

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have student data in MongoDB and I am using mongoose as orm.

I want to search all the students with the search param matching any of the student fields.

```
query = {
            find: {
                $or: [
                    { 'first_name': '/' + req.body.search_text + '/' },
                    { 'last_name': '/' + req.body.search_text + '/' },
                    { 'email': '/' + req.body.search_text + '/' },
                    { 'city': '/' + req.body.search_text + '/' },
                ]
            }
        }
```

But it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your regex correctly:

Below is the query which will find:

1. Any field contains a value.
2. Case insensitive

**Simple Query:**

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
  $or: [
    { email: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} },
    { first_name: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} },
    { last_name: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} },
    { city: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} }
  ]
})
```

**Aggregation:**

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{
  $match:{
    $or: [
      { email: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} },
      { first_name: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} },
      { last_name: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} },
      { city: {'$regex': ".*"+ req.body.search_text +".*", $options:'i'} }
    ]
  }
}])
```

Check out: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zE9k_32RQiY